# Переопределение сигналов/слотов PyQt в Designer

Tags: python, pyqt

Я уже битую неделю перекапываю просторы интернета с целью понять связку designer'а и PyQt. Безусловно, это очень мощный инструментарий, но как переопределить сигнал или слот в существующем компоненте? Предположим, я набрасываю интерфейс, перевожу файл ui в код python с помощью консольной утилиты pyuic4 и использую его как модуль. Все бы ничего, но что делать, если нужно регистрировать закрытие формы? По хорошему, необходимо переопределить closeEvent. А pyuic4 уже нагенерировал экземпляры стандартных компонентов (можете посмотреть код http://pastebin.com/v4yC1BvQ). Дальше использую так

```
from mainui import Ui_MainWindow
# лишнее опустил
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
clipboard = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()
MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()

ui = Ui_MainWindow()

ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

ui.editRegion.returnPressed.connect(CompliteRegion)
ui.editDistrict.returnPressed.connect(CompliteDistrict)
# лишнее опустил
```

, где mainui - это код по ссылке выше.

Кто не в теме, могут спросит: "Почему бы не внести изменения в mainui.py". Отвечаю, потому что интерфейс, когда разрабатываешь, постоянно изменяется, и pyuic4 будет перезаписывать этот файл после любого изменения в Designer. Поэтому я хочу сделать так, чтобы Designer создавал экземпляры моего класса. А вот как это сделать и есть вопрос.

Comment: Не понимаю почему бы в форме ui создать только виджеты, а сигналы/слоты уже в коде подключать?

Comment: @gil9red Потому что речь идет о их переопределении! Вдруг я хочу добавить сигнал кнопке.

Comment: Тогда, попробуйте у виджета вызвать disconnect и после него назначить сигналы. Вот http://pastebin.com/VympYfg1, там на клик кнопки навешивается 3 слота, после убираются связи сигнала-слота и назначается только один